# My site zooms in to top-left on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, zooming, blogger

When using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

My site still zooms in to top left on mobile devices.

This is the site: http://www.goodmoodistan.com/p/final1413.html

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: You need to stop zoom?

Comment: no, I would like to have full width when site is loading on mobile, not zoomed on the hamburger...

Comment: @digitalnomad did you noticed that you have `body {min-width:1200px;}` ? I also see that you have ***1200px*** in other place. That's why it's not working, try to fix then we maybe can start to help you the right way... Try also to think "mobile first".

Comment: Thx for your comments guys, I'll fix the body issue ! Ray C's answer solved the issue ! thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just try only width in meta tag like following:

```
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum and maximum amount the visitor can zoom

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, initial-scale=1.0">
```